# node_modules import from a directory inside what is specified in "main" (package.json)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to import from something other that what "main" points to?

In my library that is installed into node_modules, I have the main set to

```
lib/index.js
```

so (using es2015 imports - source was ts compiled js), I can do

```
import { FunctionA, FunctionB } from 'MyTestLibrary';
```

This works because these functions are exported inside of index.js under libs.

I also have an index inside a directory which exports functionC and functionD, the structure is here

```
/lib/otherdir/index.js
```

so if I do an import like so

```
import { FunctionC, FunctionD } from 'MyTestLibrary/otherdir';
```

my IDE does not complain but running the application I get a

```
Cannot find module MyTestLibrary/otherdir
```

Everything is exported as it should be.

Comment: Can you try this: 
'../../yourLibraryName' (or) '././yourLibraryName'

Comment: Library is installed in local node_modules, its not a file. A file does work but in node_modules it only seems to respect the file where the main in package.json is pointing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the directory directly like this:

```
import { FunctionC, FunctionD } from 'MyTestLibrary/lib/otherdir'
```

Comment: That works! so whats the understanding behind this ? So if you need to access any directory then i need to include the lib. I suppose the normal is everyone exports everything that is needed under lib/index.js so that the main is used ?

Comment: Using the package name alone will use the file specified as 'main' in package.json. If you want to import any other file then you can just navigate to wherever you want in the package directory.